# Finite norm for solutions of K.G. equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

Before getting into my actual question, let me give an example of a similar problem and its solutions. In non-relativistic wave function quantum mechanics, one usually assigns the Hilbert space of the theory to be $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ or something similar. However, there are many cases where we choose non normalized basis, such as $e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}$, which do not formally belong to the space of solutions. This is not an issue due to the fact that we can write any function in $L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)$ as the Fourier transform of another function in the same space,

$$\psi(\mathbf{x}) = \int d^3 p \: \tilde{\psi}(\mathbf{p})e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}.$$

Now to the actual question: Consider a basis of solutions to Klein Gordon's equations, say $\{u_{\mathbf{p}}(x),u^*_{\mathbf{p}}(x)\}$. If the index $\mathbf{p}$ is continuous, the usual normalization condition for Klein Gordon's equation reads

$$(u_{\mathbf{p}},u_{\mathbf{p}'})_{K.G.} = \delta(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{p}'),$$
$$(u^*_{\mathbf{p}},u^*_{\mathbf{p}'})_{K.G.} = -\delta(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{p}'),$$
$$(u_{\mathbf{p}},u^*_{\mathbf{p}'})_{K.G.} = 0,$$

and the sign of the inner product is used to define the positive/negative frequency modes.

If one considers a function $f(x)$, which is the solution to Klein Gordon's equation, it can then be expanded as

$$f(x) = \int d^3 p \left(\tilde{f}(\mathbf{p})u_{\mathbf{p}}(x)+\tilde{f}_*(\mathbf{p})u^*_{\mathbf{p}}(x)\right),$$

where $\tilde{f}(\mathbf{p}) = (f,u_{\mathbf{p}})$ and $\tilde{f}_*(\mathbf{p}) = -(f,u^*_{\mathbf{p}})$ are the coefficients of the expansion.

Now assume that you are given that the coefficients of this expansion are, say, of compact support. What are the properties that can be infered about $f$? Conversely, under the assumption that $f$ has a finite norm (that is, it actually belongs to the pseudo-Hilbert spaces of solutions of K.G. equation), what condition is obtained regarding the coefficients of its expansion in this basis?